# Can't Login with Twitter | Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, twitter, firebase-authentication

I added packages `firebase_auth`, `firebase_core` and `twitter_login` to my project.
And Wrote code like below

```
Future<void> signInWithTwitter() async {
  // Create a TwitterLogin instance
  final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
      apiKey: 'got from developer portal',
      apiSecretKey: 'got from developer portal',
      redirectURI: 'myappscheme://');

  await twitterLogin.login().then((value) async {
    final authToken = value.authToken;
    final authTokenSecret = value.authTokenSecret;
    if (authToken != null && authTokenSecret != null) {
      final twitterAuthCredentials = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: authToken, secret: authTokenSecret);
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredentials);
    }
    if (authToken == null) {
      print("ERROR"); // Called this everytime!
    }
  });
}
```

When I call this method by pushing button, no errors occur. But `value.authToken` is always `null`.

So I can't see any users on Firebase Auth Console.

I checked `apiKey` and `apiSecretKey` many times so I don't think these keys are problem.
And maybe `redirectURI` is not also wrong because we can get back to app after loginto Twitter on the browser.

I reffered [this official](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth#twitter) page.
Also I added `google-services.json` to `<Project>/<Android>/<app>/`.

What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After I updated Twitter API level to `Elevated` this problem has been fixed.